Question about le genre d'affixe
https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_complexe

https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9A0748

AFFIXE nom masculin Étymologie :xvie siècle, comme terme de grammaire
; xixe siècle, au sens 2. Emprunté du latin affixus, participe passé
de affigere, « attacher ».

MARQUE DE DOMAINE :LINGUISTIQUE. Élément qui s’incorpore à un mot, soit avant (préfixe), soit dans (infixe), soit après (suffixe) le
radical et qui en modifie le sens ou la fonction. L’adjectif «
suburbain » contient deux affixes : « sub », préfixe localisant, et «
ain », suffixe de dérivation.
MARQUE DE DOMAINE :MATHÉMATIQUES. Nombre complexe définissant un point du plan complexe.


https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/affixe/1485

nom masculin
(latin affixus, de affigere, attacher)

Morphème non autonome qui s'ajoute au radical d'un mot pour en modifier le sens et/ou la valeur grammaticale. (On distingue 3 types
d'affixes : les préfixes, les suffixes et les infixes.)
Marque spécifique d'un élevage de chiens ou de chats, homologuée par un organisme officiel.


https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/affixe/1486

affixe nom féminin Nombre complexe z = x + iy associé au point M (ou
au vecteur ) du plan, de coordonnées x et y.

https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/affixe

Définition de affixe​​​ nom masculin Linguistique Élément non autonome
susceptible d'être incorporé à un mot, avant, dans ou après le
radical, pour en modifier le sens ou la fonction. ➙ infixe, préfixe,
suffixe.
Définition de affixe​​​ nom féminin Mathématiques Nombre complexe z
correspondant à un point du plan tel que z = a + ib, a et b étant les
coordonnées du point.

Question : Pourquoi cette différence entre l'Académie française et les dictionnaires commerciaux de Larousse et Le Robert ?

En classe de maths, je ne suis pas sûr qu'on utilise beaucoup affixe du tout - on identifie juste le point et le nombre complexe par abus. Aussi, écrire M(z) est ennuyeux, car ça ressemble beaucoup à une fonction - c'en est une, mais bon c'est plus ou moins l'identité (par abus de nouveau).

Un ngram montre que le genre du mot affixe n'est pas fermement établi :

Son doublon affiche est d'ailleurs du genre féminin.
On ne peut émettre que des hypothèses mais il est possible que les mathématiciens aient voulu distinguer ce sens spécifique d'affixe de celui utilisé en grammaire, préfixe/infixe/suffixe/affixe masculins s'appliquant à un mot, voire à une forme d'écriture algébrique, alors qu'affixe féminin s'applique spécifiquement aux nombres imaginaires.
En tout cas, c'est le genre féminin d'affixe qui prévaut en mathématiques, ce que les Larousse et Robert ont observé et rapportent justement. Les académiciens doivent être moins férus de ce type d'ouvrage.

Il s'agit de plus que prévaloir: le genre féminin est je crois le seul et unique en mathématique. Mon petit doigt me dit que c'est inchangé depuis son introduction comme néologisme dans le contexte des nombres imaginaires, donc en latin. L'affixe grammatical est apparu ensuite avec, par mimétisme, le genre de préfixe et suffixe.
